std::jthread destructor not blocking if destroyed on coroutine activation frame?
I was playing with cpprefernce's code pulling the out_thread into resuming_on_new_thread coroutine:
#include <coroutine>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <thread>
 
using namespace std::literals;

auto switch_to_new_thread(std::jthread& out_thread) {
    struct awaitable {
        std::jthread* p_out_thread;

        bool await_ready() { return false; }
        void await_suspend(std::coroutine_handle<> h) {
            std::jthread& out_thread = *p_out_thread;
            
            if (out_thread.joinable())
                throw std::runtime_error("Output jthread parameter not empty");
    
            out_thread = std::jthread([h] { 
                // Do work:
                for(int i=1; i<=10; ++i) {
                    std::this_thread::sleep_for(10ms);
                    std::cout << i << " awaitable work: thread ID: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << '\n'; // this is OK
                }
                h.resume(); // Resume on same thread
            });
      
            // Potential undefined behavior: accessing potentially destroyed *this
            // std::cout << "New thread ID: " << p_out->get_id() << '\n';
            std::cout << "New thread ID: " << out_thread.get_id() << '\n';
        }
        void await_resume() {}
    };

    return awaitable{&out_thread};
}
 
struct task {
    struct promise_type {
        task get_return_object() { return {}; }
        std::suspend_never initial_suspend() { return {}; }
        std::suspend_never final_suspend() noexcept { return {}; }
        void return_void() {}
        void unhandled_exception() {}
    };
};
 
task resuming_on_new_thread() { 
    std::jthread out_thread;
    std::cout << "Coroutine started on thread: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << '\n';
    co_await switch_to_new_thread(out_thread);
    // awaiter destroyed here
    std::cout << "Coroutine resumed on thread: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << '\n';
    for(int i=1; i<=10; ++i) {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(10ms);
        std::cout << i << "Doing consumer work: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << '\n'; // this is OK
    }
}
 
int main() {
    std::cout << "main on thread: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << '\n';
    resuming_on_new_thread(); 
    std::cout << "main on thread: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << '\n';
    for(int i=1; i<=10; ++i) {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(10ms);
        std::cout << i << " main work: thread ID: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << '\n';
    }
} 

Surprisingly out_thread did not wait to run of consumer work post co_await. It is clear that main's work ended and coroutine's activation frame needs to be closed. I was under the impression that all local variables in the activation frame need to be properly destructed and so I expect the destructor of out_thread to be waiting for the additional work on it (as h.resume() did not complete).
See run here: https://coro.godbolt.org/z/5c9hdxvEK
But it did not wait for the "consumer" work.
Is this a feature or a bug?

Your code is a bit confusing with all those pointers and references to a thread object going around, but from the looks of it, the thread gets destructed at the end of the resuming_on_new_thread function because that's where your out_thread variable actually lives -- are you expecting it to be destructed earlier?

What happens when the main thread terminates is OS dependent. It can wait for the end of the threads or often, it is rather an immediate destruction of all the threads (so destructors are not called). It is better to create the jthread in main(), and pass its reference to the coroutine, then the main thread will wait the end of the thread.

@ChristianStieber, out_thread is not destructed at the end of resuming_on_new_thread, see: https://coro.godbolt.org/z/5c9hdxvEK (no consumer work after resuming coroutine.

@dalfaB. I agree that defining the jthread on the scope of main guarantees the blocking, nut I'm trying to understand if there are any guarantees on destruction of coroutine activation frames.
I'm using a jthread in resuming_on_new_thread. It seems that in this case main() does not neet to wait for the destruction of resuming_on_new_thread's activation frame, as if it did the destructor of out_thread would have been blocking until the completion of coroutine.
The question is: is this an expected behaviour of the compiler or a bug?

@dwto, it's not C++. When main thread terminates, all kernel object are destroyed, the coroutine frame destructor (so the jthread detructor)  is never called.
